xbbg blp.bdib function for certain commodity
I set everything up so that it works with the ticker CO1 Comdty. In the terminal CO1 Comdty Des says the exchange on which this trades is "ICE-ICE Futures Europe - Commodities". In my two files it looks as follows:
asset.yml
Comdty:
 tickers: [CL]
 exch: NYME
 freq: M
 is_fut: True
 tickers: [CO, XW]
 exch: FuturesEuropeICE
 freq: M
 is_fut: True

and in the exch.yml:
  FuturesEuropeICE:
  tz: Europe/London
  allday: [100, 2300]

As said this all works fine then with the following function call:
 blp.bdib(ticker='CO1 Comdty', dt='2024-04-17')

I know wanted to add the following ticker MOZ24 Comdty. According to the terminal under DES this trades on the exchange called "EDX-ICE Endex". I added the following to the asset file:
    tickers: [MO]
    exch: EndexICE
    freq: M
    is_fut: True

And the following to the exchange file:
  EndexICE:
  tz: Europe/Berlin
  allday: [800, 1800]

I have tried all other names for the exchange that I could think of but nothing works.
I also looked at this question
How can I figure out what the exchange is called for a certain instrument on the terminal?

What happens if you call blp.bdib(ticker='MOZ24 Comdty', dt='2024-04-17',ref='EndexICE')? This circumvents the asset->exchange lookup, but will test that the EndexICE exchange entry is valid. If this works, then you are failing to match MOZ24 Comdty to the [MO] entry, possibly because of the two digit year.

Interestingly, for me CO1 Comdty works but COZ4 Comdty does not. Probably have to step through the xbbg code to debug.

blp.bdib(ticker='MO1 Comdty', dt='2024-04-17',ref='EndexICE') this also gets me the same error:
KeyError: 'Cannot find exchange info for MO1 Comdty'

I am not sure the lookup is terribly sophisticated. From the const.py file in the xbbg source, it suggests that using blp.bdib(ticker='MOZ24 Comdty', dt='2024-04-17',ref='MO1 Comdty') will work, which it does for me.

One thing ... in my assets.yml there is a '-' in front of each 'tickers' line. I'm on xbbg 0.7.7

unfortunately this also doesnt work for me:
blp.bdib(ticker='MOZ24 Comdty', dt='2024-04-17',ref='MO1 Comdty')

How about MOZ24 Comdty with ref='FuturesEuropeICE'? And just checking you get intra-day data for MOZ24 Comdty GIP on the Terminal?

that works! which is very strange because that future contract was moved from Ice Futures Europe to ICE Endex about 3 years ago and they have not updated the mapping it seems. THANK YOU!

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Still, there should be some other way then guessing, should there not?
